# Python logging adds additional handlers

Tags: python-2.7, logging

I'm trying to get to grips with Python's logging module which frankly so far has not been approachable. Currently I have one 'main' logger in my main script:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    handler = logging.FileHandler('debug.log')
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s: %(asctime)s: %(name)s: %(message)s'))
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.debug(
        '{} run for {} using {} values.'.format(
            skill, str(datetime.now()), key, mode
        )
    )
```

and I have a secondary logger in an imported module:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
            handler = logging.FileHandler('debug.log')
            handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s: %(asctime)s: %(name)s: %(message)s'))
            logger.addHandler(handler)
```

However, although I tell both loggers to log to a file only (both only have the handlers I've set), I still get information printed to stout from the root logger. Calling logging.root.handlers shows the logger has a StreamHandler which only appears when importing the module containing the second module.

My hacking method of solving the additional stream is to just delete from the roots handlers. However, this feels like a non-canonical solution. I'm assuming I've implemented the module wrong in some way rather than this being the intended function of the module. How are you meant to set up loggers in this hierarchical fashion correctly?

Answer (score 0):

A proper [mcve] would certainly help here - I can't reproduce this root logger handler suddenly appearing out of the blue.

This being said, you're doing it wrong anyway: one of the main goals of the `logging` module and which is not clearly, explicitely documented is to separate logger's usage (`.getLogger()` and `logger.log()`) calls from logging configuration.

The point is that library code cannot know in which context it will be used - only the application will -, so library code should NOT try to configure their loggers in anyway - just get a logger and use it, period. Then it's up to the application (here your `main.py` script) to configure the loggers for the libs (hint: the `.dictConfig()` function is by far the most usable way to configure eveything at once).